# how to read files listed by ls command one by one in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I want to read all the files in a particular directory, and I want to read it one by one.

Here's what i've done so far. ls successfully get all the files from a specified directory, but could not give the file names to me one by one. It Echos the files one time only. I want to get it one by one because I need to do some parsing and use it somehwere.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Content-type: application/json
echo ""

for output in "ls /home/myComputer/Desktop/*";
do
echo $output
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
for output in /home/myComputer/Desktop/*
do
    echo $output
done
```

If there's any risk that `/home/myComputer/Desktop` is empty, please follow @JIDs advice in the comments below.

Comment: This is probably the best solution.If the OP wants to literally use ls they need to use back ticks. e.g. `for output in \`ls /home/myComputer/Desktop/*\``

Comment: ... and be careful with spaces in file names.

Comment: When the dir is empty, output will be set to `/home/myComputer/Desktop/*`.

Comment: @WalterA You can do `[[ -d /directory ]] && for i in /directory/*;do echo $i;done` to prevent that

Comment: @aioobe This will though `[[ $(ls -A /directory) ]] && for i in /directory/*;do echo $i;done`

Answer (score 0):

The next solution also works when the dir is empty.

```
ls /home/myComputer/Desktop/ 2>/dev/null |while read -r output; do
    echo ${output}
done
```

This construction is nice to know, for when you want to split the input lines in some fields:

```
cat someFile | while read -r field1 field2 remainingfields; do
```

Comment: Parsing ls and then piping into a while loop is poor coding as it using cat unnecessarily to pipe into the while loop.

Comment: @JID : I prefer the `ls | while ` above `[[ $(ls -A /directory) ]] && for i in /directory/*;do echo $i;done `

Comment: Any particular reason ? Because there are many reasons not to do it your way :)

Comment: @JID Construction also works in ksh, I only write the path /directory once and I only look for files in /directory once. Still not perfect, we should use  find for directories with files with a space.